# before_filter with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, before-filter

I'm using Devise's built in `before_filter :authenticate_user!`. I want to call my own custom method in my application helper if a user fails the before filter (tries to do an action when logged out). How and where can I do this?

Comment: You look into using CanCan for authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would write a custom before filter that uses `user_signed_in?`. This will just return a boolean, and not do any of the redirect-type actions that `authenticate_user!` does.

So, you could write a before filter like this:

```
before_filter :custom_user_auth
...
def custom_user_auth
    unless user_signed_in?
        # Do custom stuff, ultimately restricting access to the 
        # ...protected resource if it needs to be
    end
end
```

Do note that this before filter won't protect your resource from unauthorized users unless the inside area of that `unless` statement redirects or renders.

Comment: can I put the method in my application controller?

Comment: If you plan to use the before filter in multiple controllers, each of which extend the ApplicationController, then I'd define the function there. However, I would definitely not put the `before_filter` line in the application controller, since you probably only want to use this in certain instances.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of calling `before_filter :authenticate_user!` write your own function in your controller that calls `authenticate_user!`. Something like:

```
before_filter :logged_in

...

private
def logged_in
  your_function
  authenticate_user!
end
```