# Rails 3 - Devise IP based authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, devise

I am trying to let GoogleBot login to my website and bypass the authentication.
The web site uses devise for its authentication and I was thinking about creating a username for google and then let GoogleBot automatically login to that user.

The way I want to identify GoogleBot is based on its IP addresses.

Is there anyway to link a list of IP addresses to a username and bypass the login process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a warning: Google has a policy that it will not index content that cannot be accessed without a login.    There's a special policy in effect that gets around this limitation called "First Click Free" (see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/10/first-click-free-for-web-search.html) used by sites like ExpertExchange.  If you violate this policy, google may penalize your site effectively removing it from most searches.  Google webmaster central is also a good resource for this stuff, see http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40349, as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the page and it says we can let googlebot see the content of any page if we follow the above rule, which is fine. What I need to know is how to make sure that googlebot can bypass Devise authentication.

Comment: To let GoogleBot bypass Devise, first write a method that verifies the request is from an authentic googlebot IP, maybe call it `valid_robot?`, then write a method in `application_controller.rb` called something like `custom_authenticate_user!`.  That method would cal your `valid_robot?` method and just return true accordingly, or pass along to Devise's `authenticate_user!` method.  Finally in a before filter for the pages you want to let bots into, replace/add calls to your custom authentication method.  See 2nd answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034410/before-filter-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is to detect the IP and then simulate a login if you've already created a login for google's bot.

If you've created the account already, you can add code in your default action to automatically login for the google bot once it hits that action.

Broadly,

```
# ......
# ......
#inside the controller that has the application's home route

def index #assuming index is the default action
  ip = request.remote_ip
  if ip == Google
    #redirect to login with the account you created for google
  else
    #other processing
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure if googlebot stores cookies so this approach might not work.

Comment: You would have to have more sophisticated code than just checking the IP address; multiple crawlers from different addresses can be accessing your content around the same time, so you may get a different crawler instance or server on subsequent requests.  Here's google's suggestion for detecting an authentic GoogleBot: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553