# Devise public user page only if user is pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise user model with pro boolean column.I want to build a public page for each of them but only if user is pro.How can i approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite straightforward.

First you need to change your user.rb model and add the new column to the attr_accessible, so it looks something like ...

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :pro
```

Now you can use the following statement to test if a user is a 'pro' ...

```
if current_user.pro
    #some page display code
end
```

You can also use a before_filter in the controller which displays your public page, you'll need to read the devise documentation a bit more and perhaps check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034410/before-filter-with-devise)

Answer (score 0):

If you build public page, you propably use `User.find(params[:id])` for get user information. Change that to `User.where(:id => params[:id], :pro => true).first`. Then just check that user exist or we had only nil.