# rails devise how to specify view/controller action need sign in

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I simply can do a

```
if not user_signed_in? 
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
```

for each action need authentication. I imagine there should be more elegant way to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controllers that should have user authentication.

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

If not all actions in the controller require user authentication, implement a custom before filter as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034498/429758

If the whole application needs user authentication, then the above line belongs in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file.